# SQL If Statement Not Working Correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, if-statement

My if statement never seems to do anything. I am inputting @active from an ASP page, and @cactive is set through the selecting of CActive from the Cots Table. Do you guys see anything wrong with this statement? Why doesn't it ever execute? Im using SQL Server 2005

```
//Declare Variables Here (about 20)

AS
If @currentdate is null
SET @currentdate = GETDATE()

Update Cots
SET //UPDATE ALL FIELDS HERE
Where CoID = @CID

SET @cactive =
(
Select CActive
From Cots
Where CoID = @CID
)

If @cactive != @active
Begin
INSERT INTO Activity
        (CoID,ActivityDate, ActivityName, ActivityNote, ActivityMediaContact, ActivityOwner)
        Values (@CID, @currentdate, 'Co ' + @fname + ' ' + @lname + 'made inactive','Co made inactive on ' + CAST(@currentdate AS varchar(50)), 'User', 'User')
End

INSERT INTO Activity
        (CoID,ActivityDate, ActivityName, ActivityNote, ActivityMediaContact, ActivityOwner)
        Values (@CID, @currentdate, 'Updated ' + @fname + ' ' + @lname,'Updated on ' + CAST(@currentdate AS varchar(50)), 'User', 'User')
```

Comment: What are the data types of @active and @cactive?

Comment: @BenHoffstein varchar(5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If either of these is null, they will never be equal or not equal

```
If @cactive != @active
```

Example

```
DECLARE @i int, @i2 int
IF @i <> @i2
PRINT 'not equal'

IF @i = @i2
PRINT 'equal'
```

Check for NULLS also by using `ISNULL()/COALESCE()` or `IS NULL/IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Using IS NULL is best for checking a condition, like in a WHERE clause.

You should use the ISNULL() function...

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT AVG(ISNULL(Weight, 50))
FROM Production.Product;
GO
```